# Databases: What Option is Best for my Project

Tags: sql, xml, database

I'm designing an internal website for a small company I work for. I am comfortable in my ability to do the CSS and HTML and I'm willing to learn how to do whatever else will be needed.

The company is a transportation company that services many towns throughout the day. I have a table (in Excel format currently) of cities that we service along with a correlating zip code and pickup terminal. I would like the dispatchers to be able to enter the cities they are no longer able to service into a search bar and their input would search the previously mentioned table, copy the city, zip, and pickup terminal, and write it to a new table.

The customer service team would then be able to search the newly written table by either city, zip, or pickup terminal to see which cities we no longer service and provide feedback to our customers.

My question is what is the best way to go about this without the need for paid services? My table will contain less than 1000 rows (could easily be reduced to less than 500 if that changes things) and 3 columns and the table being written off of it will have less than 200 rows and 3 columns by the end of the business day.

I've never made a website that needed a database before and I don't know what my best option is for such a small table. I've looked into XML, SQL, and even Google Spreadsheets for options but I just don't know enough about databases to make an informed decision.

Answer (score 1):

1000 rows of 3 columns is not a large amount of data; you could create a JSON or even a text file and load it into RAM. If you create a class for your data you could use dictionaries or maps to query it.

I would not worry about a database until performance or integrity becomes a bottleneck.

Comment: I'm thinking of going this route. I've converted my data to a JSON array but I'm lost as far as how to proceed. Could you expand on how I would utilize LINQ for my needs?

Comment: Whatever programming language you are using should have a JSON library; use it and do not consider writing your own. LINQ is a feature of C# and I do not know if that is the language you are using. Even if it is, learn how to read JSON files first. Get some sample code, write a test program. Did it work? If not, post your code to a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a site that might give you some guidance: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/database/article.php/3478121

I've had a lot of success with google sheets for some small-scale back-end data, kind of similar to your project. But we had an experienced developer who then used python to set it up. Also, if you want to scale your data set eventually, Google sheets may not be the way to go. I'd look into SQL as a long-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

**my-sql** is a good choice
you can make your work easier by downloading **xampp**
it is free opensource software it contains **apache server, mysql database** **,php,perl** interpreter and other utilities.
it also has '**phpMyAdmin**' utility which gives you easy ways to create databases and tables without even knowing much of code of sql statements. but to add functionality you mentioned above you will need to write the back end of your website using php,asp,jsp,python or any other language you know, that takes time to do,
you can download xampp from
  
https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html
that will do it

http://www.w3schools.com

is helpful for tutorials on web development.